# Can you identify the parts for this red wizard?

Tags: part-identification, minifigure-identification

Can anyone identify the hair, head, or the sapphire gem in [this photo?](https://www.flickr.com/photos/87786514@N02/15739668000/in/photostream/)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Hair :

[image]

[Part # 16691pb01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=16691pb01#T=C&C=1)

Minifigure, Hair Long with Nougat Headband Pattern

- Head :

[image]

[Part # 3626cpb0931](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0931#T=C&C=90)

Minifigure, Head Dual Sided Black Eyebrows, Cheek Lines, Chin Dimple, Determined / Bared Teeth with Red Eyes Pattern (Superman) - Hollow Stud

- Gem:

[image]

[Part # 30153](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30153#T=C&C=17)

Rock 1 x 1 Jewel 24 Facet 
in Transred